# Como posso separar um botão e um campo de texto em componentes - React JS

Tags: react

Estou começando com `ReactJS` e resolvi separar algumas partes em componentes, um `<botao />` e um campo para escrever.

O aplicativo que está criando é simples, é um campo para escrever com dois botões para alterar o texto em  minúsculas ou maiúsculas.

O código em que está funcionando, ele parou de funcionar quando resolver separar em um componente, imaginar que há algum erro de lógica, mas não consegue encontrar uma solução.

Esse é o erro que está aparecendo.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

App.js

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Botao.js

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Campo.js

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `this.state.message` não faz parte do botão ... !

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que existam melhores formas de fazer isso, do jeito que tu fez está errado porque o estado `this.state.message` não faz parte do `Component` `<Botao />`, um exemplo mínimo de mudança para minúsculo ou maiúsculo de um componente `<textarea/>`:

```js
class Botao extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.callBack}>
      {this.props.status?"Maiusculo":"Minusculo"}
      </button>
    )
  }
}
class Texto extends React.Component {  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setMessage = this.setMessage.bind(this);
    this.state = { message:'abcdef' };
  }
  setMessage(e) { 
    let message = this.props.status ?
      e.target.value.toLowerCase() :
      e.target.value.toUpperCase();
    this.setState({message});
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.status !== this.props.status) {
      let message = this.props.status ?
          this.state.message.toLowerCase() :
          this.state.message.toUpperCase();
      this.setState({message});
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>        
        <textarea cols="50" rows="5" 
          value={this.state.message} 
          onChange={e => this.setMessage(e)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      status: true
    }
    this.callAction =
      this.callAction.bind(this);
  }
  callAction() {
    let status = this.state.status ? false: true;
    this.setState({status});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Botao status={this.state.status} 
            callBack={this.callAction}/> 
        <Texto status={this.state.status} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Observação: na minha visão esse componente não deveria ser quebrado em 3 porque eles fazem parte do mesmo processo e só complicou a lógica e atualizações do mesmo, mas, acho também que tenha separado por motivos de aprender.

Comment: Sim, como estou começando agora React, eu resolvi separar por componentes pra ver se eu entendi mesmo, mas acabei complicando mais o código.

Na sua visão, não seria necessário fazer essa divisão ?

Comment: @GuilhermeRamos para esse componente não precisava! tudo é uma relação